# How to aggregate columns using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to manipulate the sql statement as below.

I have following table.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
USER_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
MENU VARCHAR(20),
FREQ integer,
RANK integer
)
```

After inserting some records, the table can be seen as below.

```
USER_NAME        MENU            FREQ           RANK
User1            PIZZA           5              1
User1            PIE             3              2
User1            HAMBURGER       2              3
User1            RICE            1              4
User2            ICECREAM        15             1
User2            FISH            9              2
User2            HAMBURGER       2              3
User2            RICE            1              4
```

Then, I would like to convert it as below on by grouping the values based on the USER_NAME.

```
USER_NAME           MOST_FREQUENCY_MENU        MENU_WITH_FREQ
USER1               PIZZA                      PIZZA:5,PIE:3,HAMBURGER:2,RICE:1
USER2               ICECREAM                   ICECREAM:15,FISH:9,HAMBURGER:2,RICE:1
```

How to achieve this sql?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: mysql version is above 8.0

Comment: whatever answer you DO get, I dont know if Freq and Rank should be varchar if they are holding integers.  Try to keep data types proper to what their intent.  Same thing with datetime fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by user and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get the list of menus in descending order:

```
SELECT USER_NAME,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(MENU ORDER BY FREQ DESC), ',', 1) MOST_FREQUENCY_MENU, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(MENU, ':', FREQ ORDER BY FREQ DESC) MENU_WITH_FREQ
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY USER_NAME;
```

or:

```
SELECT USER_NAME,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(MENU ORDER BY `RANK`), ',', 1) MOST_FREQUENCY_MENU, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(MENU, ':', FREQ ORDER BY `RANK`) MENU_WITH_FREQ
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY USER_NAME;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=571c2133503e6a0de576af21bc43397f).